# What is the Azure Data Lake Storage (gen1) account name and storage account key?

Tags: azure, apache-nifi, azure-data-lake

I am trying to configure 'ADLSCredentialsControllerService' in Apache Nifi. It expects to provide storage account name and storage account key, as shown in the image below.
[image: ADLSCredentialControllerService configuration page]
I am not able to find the storage account name and storage account key in the portal. Where or how can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find these values by navigating to your underlying storage account -> Access Keys
and generate a SAS token by navigating to **`SAS token`** in the portal

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How to identify the underlying storage account. I did not provide any such information during creation of AzureDataLakeStorage either.

Comment: it should be straight forward, open your ADLS and there should be way to see underlying storage account